# Comparing SSID to a string

Tags: string, android-wifi, ssid

I have trying to do something when I get to know that in my wifilist this SSID is present

My code is somewhat :

```
List<ScanResult> wifilist = wifi.getScanResults();

for(int i=0;i<wifilist.size();i++){
 if (wifilist.get(i).SSID.equals("Wifi1")){

                        // Do somthing  
                      }
}
```

Where Wifi1 is name of the wifi network.

But I m not able to do so as if it seem wifilist.get(i).SSID isn't able to compare it to "Wifi1". If you can tell me where I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
     WifiManager mWifiManager;

   List<ScanResult> mScanResults = mWifiManager.getScanResults();

    for(ScanResult results : mScanResults) {

        Log.d("SSID  result", results.SSID);

        if (results.SSID.equals("WIFI NAME")) {

            break;
        }


    }
```

Comment: This isn't substantially different from the OP's version.

Comment: @Kenster i dnt understand OP's version?

Answer (score 0):

What does `wifilist.get(i).SSID.getClass()` say? If it isn't `java.lang.String`, then you most probably need to call `.toString()` and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

SSID has double quotation marks. Instead of

```
SSID.equals("Wifi1")
```

you should use

```
SSID.equals("\"Wifi1\"")
```